# Find steady-state solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Governing equation:

$$\frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 \Omega}{\partial x^2} -DH \frac{\partial \Omega}{\partial x} $$
Find the steady-state solution $\Omega(x)$ from the governing equation with boundary conditions $\Omega(0) = 1$ and $\Omega(1) = 0$.

Comment: what does Ω(x) equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steady state solution occurs when $\Omega_t = 0$.  The steady-state obeys the equation (assuming $DH$ is a constant)

$$\Omega''(x) - DH \Omega'(x) = 0$$

with BC's $\Omega(0) =1$ and $\Omega(1)=0$.  The solution is

$$\Omega(x) = A+B e^{DH x}$$

where $A+B = 1$ and $A + B e^{DH} = 0$.